# Java / LWJGL Pong AI issue

Tags: java, if-statement, artificial-intelligence, lwjgl

I am struggling with what must be a basic concept, but can you have a look at my issue?

I have the code where: ai moves the player bat, HEIGHT = total height of Display, and batHeight is the size of the pong paddle/bat:

```
public void ai(int bally, int HEIGHT, int batHeight) {
    if (bally < this.y + ySize / 2) {
        if (this.y <= 0) {
            System.out.println("Upper Bound");
           y = 0;
        } else {
            y -= 2;
        }
    }
    if (bally > this.y + ySize / 2) {
        if (this.y >= HEIGHT - batHeight) {
            System.out.println("Lower Bounds");
            y = HEIGHT - batHeight;
        } else {
            y += 2;
        }
    }
}
```

The above does exactly what I want it to do. Pong Bat moves up, and when it hits the top of the screen, it prints the console line, and stops the Bat. Exactly the same happens at the bottom of the screen. It prints the console, and stops the bat. It does this every time with no issues.

Now, if I modify the code slightly:

```
public void ai(int bally, int HEIGHT, int batHeight) {
    if (bally < this.y + ySize / 2) {
        if (this.y <= 0) {
            System.out.println("Upper Bound");
            y = 0;
        } else {
            if(rand.nextInt(2)+1 == 1){
                y -= 2;
            }else{
                y -=3;
            }
        }
    }
    if (bally > this.y + ySize / 2) {
        if (this.y >= HEIGHT - batHeight) {
            System.out.println("Lower Bounds");
            y = HEIGHT - batHeight;
        } else {
            y += 2;
        }
    }
}
```

It iterates once, stopping at the top bound, but then it loses itself, and forgets the bounds and the bat moves off the screen. I have Console printing the Bat y position, and it tracks with no issue, accurately displaying its y co-ord, but after the first iteration, it goes to negative y and greater that screen height.

I did have the theory that you cannot nest a IF inside an ELSE statement, so i tried moving it around so that it read:

```
if(this.y != 0){
    if(rand.nextInt(2) + 1 == 1){ 
        //move the paddle at speed 1
    } else {
        //move paddle at speed 2
    }
}else{
    //do not move the paddle
}
```

But that made no difference.

The idea behind the code was to add some chance for the AI bat. Sometimes its fast, and other times it is slower.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Is it possible that you have more than one `y` variable? I don't think so, because it worked with the first code. Anyways: Try putting an `else` in front of your second outside `if` (the one that says `bally > this.y + ySize / 2`) because it's possible that, in some cases, both `if` statements are being activated. Also, be aware of the pitfalls of integer division-- that might be related.

Comment: Also, fyi, it is perfectly fine to have nested `if` statements. Just keep track of which one you're matching your `else`s to :)

Comment: Thanks, it was just a theory about the nested if in an else!

Comment: Answer the question so I can Plus 1 you :) worked a treat. 2 bats now with fully working AI stopping at bound, with a 25% chance of slow movements!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code from far away looks like this:

```
for a given time:
if the ball is below the paddle {
    if the paddle is below the screen, put it back
    else move it down 2 or 3 units
}
if the ball is above the paddle {
    if the paddle is above the screen, put it back
    else move it up 2 units
}
```

Imagine the case where the ball is at y = 1 and the paddle is at y = 2. The first `if` statement will be triggered (1 < 2), the paddle is not outside (2 > 0), so it moves down 2 or 3 units. Let's say 3, for argument's sake. Now, paddle is at y = -1, the ball is still at y = 1. Now, the condition for the second big `if` is true! So we enter it: the paddle's not above, and we move it up two units. Now, the paddle is at y = 1...

It is clear that it should not have entered the second loop. So, stick an `else` in front of it, because it should only ever enter one :)